# Checking regex in rails TestCase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

So in Rails I've written these validations for an email :

```
validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A[^@\s]+@([^@\s]+\.)+[^@\s]+\z/
```

When I try to submit something with a wrong email this works because it sends me an error, but when I try to test it like this :

```
test "should not save if email is not valid" do
    slogan = Slogan.create(firstname: 'tristan', lastname: 'vermeesch', email: 'titivermeeschgmail.com', slogan: 'Test')
    assert slogan.valid?, "Tried to save with an email that is not valid"
  end
```

The test fails, can someone please help?

Comment: What are you trying to test in the 2nd scenario? The error message?

Comment: I'm testing that an invalid email shouldn't be saved @AsimHashmi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to test that your model should not be saved and it should have errors when wrong email is given, you can use the valid? method and error? property.
Your test would be like this:

```
test "should not save if email is not valid" do
    slogan = Slogan.create(firstname: 'tristan', lastname: 'vermeesch', email: 'titivermeeschgmail.com', slogan: 'Test')
    assert_not_nil slogan.errors[:email]
  end
```

Comment: This looks like you are testing the same thing twice...maybe remove `assert_equal slogan.valid?, false`?